# How to change level of counters in animation for Tecplot360

Tags: animation

I am working on a transient heat transfer problem. The problem that I have is as the time goes the range of temperature is changing but Tecplot only use one sort of levels for contour for all of time steps. Therefore the change in temperature is not very sensible at the end of the time which transient diminishes.
I am wondering if there is anyway to change the levels of contours as time goes forward? (Could I specify a contour for any specific time step?)

Comment: I think the question might be better suited to Computational Science SE. I've seem other CFD  and Tecplot questions there.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write a macro to do that and save the animation. Have a look at the tecplot macro scripting guide [Tecplot Scripting Guide](http://download.tecplot.com/360/current/360_scripting_guide.pdf). You can record the macro, then load your data cycle through a few time steps and change the level of contour manually. Then you can edit the recorded macro to suit your self. The following macro file should be helpful for starting guideline

```
#!MC 1410
$!EXPORTSETUP
  EXPORTFNAME="movie.avi"
  EXPORTFORMAT=AVI
  EXPORTREGION = CURRENTFRAME
$!EXPORTSTART
$Loop 20
  $!GLOBALTIME |LOOP| # assuming your time varies as 1, 2, 3, ... 20
  $!CONTOURLEVELS RESETTONICE
  $!EXPORTNEXTFRAME
$!ENDLOOP
$!EXPORTEND
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's been a while since i asked this question and I can't use your code right now, I'll try your solution in the future if i had to use tecplot again.